# Prevent unloading a bitmap from RAM

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I have 2 large bitmaps in AIR project and want to switch their visibility to user rapidly (only one bitmap is shown at the same time).

I've tried to load both bitmaps at an application start and keep them in memory, so I can show the first one and hide the second one (or vice versa) in a moment.

But by default the platform unloads hidden bitmap after 30 seconds: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-576ba64d124318d7189-7ff8.html

This behaviour results in delay for loading into RAM the previously unloaded bitmap once again. It takes about 10 seconds which is too long.

How could I address it?

Comment: Are you applying filters to the bitmaps? If so, are you manipulating the parameters for the filters? That seems to be the only occasion where the "dynamic bitmap unloading" would kick in and where it would pose a problem. This shouldn't apply to a normal Bitmap. (At least not in the way described in the link.)

Comment: By the way; 10 seconds to load the image into memory? What size are those pictures?

Comment: @walkietokyo about 15000x12000

Comment: also, no filters are applied

Comment: I'm surprised to hear that it works _at all_ considering that the maximum total number of pixels of a `BitmapData` object is 16,777,215! You are using images more than ten times that size.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you're lucky the `Bitmap` will even load. Per [the LiveDocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html):

> In AIR 1.5 and Flash Player 10, the maximum size for a BitmapData object is 8,191 pixels in width or height, and the total number of pixels cannot exceed 16,777,215 pixels. (So, if a BitmapData object is 8,191 pixels wide, it can only be 2,048 pixels high.) In Flash Player 9 and earlier and AIR 1.1 and earlier, the limitation is 2,880 pixels in height and 2,880 in width.

Anyway, instead of saving the `Bitmap` itself, why not save the `BitmapData`? Then you just create a new Bitmap using the BitmapData each time you want to make the image visible.

If that also has a cutoff (don't see why it would), you could try using `BitmapData.getPixels()` which outputs a `ByteArray`. Each time you need to load the Bitmap, you do a `BitmapData.setPixels( ByteArray )` and then add the BitmapData to a new Bitmap object.

Be warned: that last method will be slow, very slow.

Regardless, you should probably think about decreasing the size of your images or look into a tile system. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx) regarding the Bing Maps tile system for an idea of what to do there (it's a great, well put together article regardless of application). That is obviously much more complicated than you would need, but 256x256 (which both Bing and Google use) is a good size for tiling large images. It's small enough to be loaded quickly and on-demand so that you can have them disappear when outside the viewport (the more `DisplayObject`s on the stage, the slower it runs)

Comment: Creating new Bitmap is unnecessary, it's enough to call `theBitmap.bitmapData=storedBitmapData;` and the existing Bitmap object will update. A Bitmap is a BitmapData's wrapper to display it, that's all.

Comment: I wasn't sure how the Bitmap objects were being "hidden" here (no experience with this particular problem). If they were being GCd, you would need to crate a new Bitmap. I figured just creating a new one each time was the safest route.

Answer (score 0):

We have had a similar problem in our projects. We found that AIR will get rid of the uncompressed image data of a loaded bitmap, if the bitmap is not rendered on screen in the last 10 seconds. The runtime keeps the compressed PNG or JPG data around though, so the image can be re-uncompressed on demand the next time it needs to be rendered. This causes quite a delay in our apps though, when it has to decompress large images.

Our fix involves never removing any image (that needs to be quickly displayed later) from the stage: When an image is supposed to be removed, set it to alpha 0.001 at the top of the stage instead. It won't be visible on screen, but Flash will still have to render it. This fix sounds like it will be terrible for rendering-performance, but we actually didn't notice any difference with the "almost transparent" bitmaps hanging around on the stage.

Despite this fix, you might have some problems though: If nothing changes on the screen, the runtime won't even bother to do a render pass. If nothing renders over an extended period (about 10 seconds), Flash will again start to throw away unneeded bitmaps, even if they are visible on the stage. We used another technique to force Flash to keep rendering:

1. Create a tiny rectangle, with alpha set to 0.001. Add it on the top layer of the stage.
2. Create a Timer with a 1 second delay, repeating forever.
3. Every time the Timer triggers, move the rectangle to a random position on the stage.

This will force Flash to do a render-pass, at least once every second.

Note: The limits on bitmap-sizes were completely removed in AIR 3 (and Flash Player 11). So today, if your image can fit in RAM, you can load it!